# Javascript in Datatables cell

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables, and have to have confirmation scripts in certain cells. However, since the use of ' causes the script to not fire (' within '), how can I get around this? Example below (the onclick event won't fire, I get sent to the link immediately).

```
var dataSet = [["<a href='member_search.aspx' onclick='return confirm('Please confirm?'); return false;' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>radera</a>", "Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "<a href='member_details.aspx'>info</a>"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `&quot;` :

```
onclick='return confirm(&quot;Please confirm?&quot;); return false;'
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/962/**

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the extra quotes:

```
onclick='return confirm(\'Please confirm?\')
```

Answer (score 0):

i will use this code and run properly , plz try ..

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript:return confirm(\"Do you want to do this : {0}\")", Eval("ID")) %>'>
```

Thank you